# regular expression match in salt-stack

Tags: regex, puppet, salt-stack

I'm rewriting some modules from puppet to saltstack.

In puppet we can use `node` to specific this part is for this machine,
for example:

```
node /william\d+.aws.dev/ {
  # some codes here.. 
}
```

But in saltstack, it's not that much elegant:

```
{% if grains['fqdn'] == 'william.aws.dev' %}
  # some codes here..
{% endif %}
```

and regular expression is not supported.

Is there any way to rewrite it in saltstack using less code?

---

**Note** I don't want to use `top.sls` to define which node using which sls. because it would make the top.sls file too large to maintain.

I just want to define a simple two line in `top.sls`:

```
'*':
  - node.*
```

everytime I add some node in salt, I just need to create a new file under the `node` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would still recommend assigning SLSes to nodes in your topfile, simply because the way you have it set up right now, every node gets served a copy of every single SLS under `node/` directory, with the logic of which states to run encoded in the SLSes themselves. This seems a bit messy to me, considering that you can do all of this logic and regex related matching in your `top.sls`.

> everytime I add some node in salt, I just need to create a new file under the node directory.

OK, you can get this functionality by using only `top.sls` while still keeping it at a manageable size. It seems that your intent is to have each node get its own SLS file, and to assign nodes to the SLS matching their `fqdn`. If that is the case, then take a look at this example `top.sls`, tweaked from the [salt grains documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/grains.html)

```
{% set grain_fqdn = salt['grains.get']('fqdn', '') %}

base:
  'fqdn:{{ grain_fqdn }}':
      - match: grain  
      - node.{{ grain_fqdn }}
```

This will ensure that the node with grain `fqdn = williams.aws.dev` get's assigned the `node.williams.aws.dev.sls` state file. **Note** your `match` here can use any sort of regex or compound matching that salt allows: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/

Comment: but if there is not sls name "node.williams.aws.dev.sls" would cause error. because I don't need all nodes have sls file.